# Procurar arquivo em diretório

Tags: php, diretório

Tenho um diretório na rede com milhares de arquivos TXT gerados por um outro software contratado na empresa.

O arquivo é nomeado com a seguinte lógica:

```
 (cpf do cliente)(data da insercao)(hora insercao).txt
 1234567894120150501142024.txt
```

Preciso selecionar o `txt` correspondente ao CPF do cliente informado, porém não estou conseguindo procurar o arquivo.

Comment: Você possui as informações necessárias pra buscar este arquivo?(cpf ,data e hora de inserção)

Comment: Possuo apenas o cpf, e este arquivo é único, gerado somente ao inserir um novo cliente.
Queria algo tipo LIKE do mysql, para que assim buscasse todos os arquivos com o cpf no inicio.

Comment: publiquei minha resposta

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Utiliza a função [glob()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.glob.php) para isso.

```
foreach (glob("00000000000*") as $file) {
    $user = $file;
}
```

Note que na definição do padrão existe um `*` que serve para definir que tudo o que vier após o `$cpf` é irrelevante para a busca, sendo assim você receberá como retorno todos os arquivos que possuam no início um valor que seja igual ao CPF igual ao buscado.

Answer (score 2):

Não testei, mas acredito que o [glob()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) vai resolver o problema. Se você sabe o CPF, pode fazer algo como

```
$cpf = "12345678900*";
    foreach (glob($cpf) as $arq) {
    echo "$arq" ."\n";
}
```

ele devolve o nome do arquivo que tem o cpf que você passou.